# Problem of system font detection with gdtools::font_family_exists

Tags: r, fonts, font-family, ggiraph

I want to draw an interactive html plot with `ggiraph` changing the font to "DejaVu Sans Condensed".
This particular font works well with the interactive tooltips of `girafe` when I put it in the css,
but not as the general font for text elements in the html plot itself.
Lets try with an example. First, everything works fine with ggplot2 :

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggiraph)
windowsFonts(sans = windowsFont("DejaVu Sans Condensed")) 
z <- ggplot(data = iris, 
            mapping = aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Petal.Width)) +
  geom_point() +
  ggtitle("Title with special characters ♀♂") +
  xlab("Sepal.Length ♀♂") + ylab("Miles per Gallon ♀♂" ) + 
    theme_minimal(base_family = "sans", base_size = 18)
z
```

[image]

We can see that the DejaVu Sans Condensed font worked, because the male and female symbols
in the titles appear as bold as the letters.
But with `girafe`, symbols appears thinner because font doesn’t work/went back to Arial :

```
girafe(ggobj = z, fonts = list(sans = "DejaVu Sans Condensed"))
```

[image]

The problem may come from the `gdtools` package which `ggiraph` uses to manage fonts,
because it cannot find DejaVu Sans Condensed :

```
gdtools::font_family_exists("DejaVu Sans Condensed")
# [1] FALSE
```

However, if we use `gdtools::sys_fonts`, we can find DejaVu Sans Condensed, but with
an incomplete font family name :

```
gdtools::sys_fonts() %>% filter(str_detect(name, "DejaVuSansCondensed")) %>% select(3:5)

# A tibble: 4 x 3
# name                              family         style                 
# DejaVuSansCondensed-Bold          DejaVu Sans    Condensed Bold        
# DejaVuSansCondensed-BoldOblique   DejaVu Sans    Condensed Bold Oblique
# DejaVuSansCondensed-Oblique       DejaVu Sans    Condensed Oblique     
# DejaVuSansCondensed               DejaVu Sans    Condensed
```

"DejaVu Sans Condensed" exists, but the "family" name is simply "Deja Vu Sans",
and the "Condensed" part went to "style" (while on the medatada of this font in my computer,
using Windows, the font family name is "DejaVu Sans Condensed").

Is it a problem with the system font detection algorithm ? Or is it a normal behavior,
and then where to specify the Condensed style to use it in `ggiraph` ?

Thanks,

Comment: I think ‘gdtools’ is correct: [the family name *is* “DejaVu Sans”](https://dejavu-fonts.github.io/). “Condensed” isn’t part of the family name, it’s the style. Applications often take liberty with the way they display font names, particularly when they don’t recognise something as a style (such as the “Condensed” style here). So: have you tried using “DejaVu Sans” with the style “Condensed”?

Comment: The problem is that I can find no way to set the style "Condensed" neither in `ggplot2` nor `ggiraph` (all I can do is to put `face` to `"c(plain", "bold", "italic", "bold.italic")`).

Comment: Have you tried just using `DejaVuSansCondensed` as the family? That works for me. The issue at least for ‘ggplot2’ is that it hard-codes a subset of the valid typefaces (no idea why) — also, the typeface is connected to the font family by a dash when looking up the filename, so it would attempt to load `DejaVuSans-Condensed.ttf` rather than `DejaVuSansCondensed.ttf`.

Comment: I think a nice solution would be to let ggiraph use a ttf file in addition to family name. We will try that soon

Comment: Unfortunately, with `DejaVuSansCondensed` as the family, I can’t make it work with `ggplot2` nor `ggiraph`.